# Why does the wall do zero work on the spring + block system?

Tags: potential-energy, spring

The left side of the spring is attached to the wall, and there is a block attached to the right side of the spring. If the spring is compressed to the left, why does the wall do zero work on the spring + block system?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Work is done when a force is applied and the point of contact moves. In your example, the point of contact between the spring and the wall does not move - rather the entire spring expands and it is therefore the spring which does work.

A similar situation occurs when you climb the stairs. The stairs do not do work on you. Your body does the work by pushing the muscles and bones into a new position while applying force on them.